# Errror Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'md-select'

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2

I have this error while I'm integrating the select component in material design2

Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'md-select'.

Template:

```
   <md-select placeholder="Favorite food" [(ngModel)]="selectedValue" name="food">
            <md-option *ngFor="let food of foods" [value]="food.value">
              {{food.viewValue}}
            </md-option>
          </md-select>
```

Component code

```
....
 selectedValue: string;

     foods = [
       {value: 'steak-0', viewValue: 'Steak'},
       {value: 'pizza-1', viewValue: 'Pizza'},
       {value: 'tacos-2', viewValue: 'Tacos'}
     ];

.....
```

and the select is imported in my module like indicated in the documentation.

Any Ideas how I can fix that ?

Comment: Have you imported the MaterialModule in your main.ts ?

Comment: `and the select is imported in my module like indicated in the documentation.`
Can you provide your code to illustrate this?

Comment: Did you import the `FormsModule` module?

Comment: Importation  import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

/* Material design */
import {
      MaterialModule,
      MdAutocompleteModule,
     MdButtonModule,
     MdSelectModule
  .....
 } from '@angular/material';
import 'hammerjs';

@NgModule({
    imports: [ //Modules
    FormsModule,
     MyClientRoutingModule,
     MaterialModule,
      MdSelectModule,
   ......

Comment: The version of material is --> 2.0.0-beta.10

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add `FormsModule` in the `AppModule` or any other module `imports` entry where you are using `<md-select>`. Also, remove `MaterialModule` from your imports, it is depreciated.

```
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

....
imports: [ FormsModule ]
```

Comment: The FormsModule is imported

Comment: Create a plunker with your code, see my answer update as well.